# Подключение django-emoji-picker к проекту

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, form

Захотел подключить эмоджи к полям формы, нашел готовый проект, который необходимо было установить через Pip, ссылка на проект https://pypi.org/project/django-emoji-picker/. Установил успешно, подключил как указано автором и не работает, в поле инпута нет иконки как у автора, хотя параметр задан такой же `test = forms.CharField(widget=EmojiPickerTextInputAdmin)`. Решил попробовать задать другой параметр `test = forms.CharField(widget=forms.Textarea)`, но мое поля test осталось input вместо Textarea. Может я не правильно передаю параметры или необходимо еще, что то для подключения данного виджета?

Моя форма:

```
from django import forms
from emoji_picker.widgets import EmojiPickerTextInputAdmin, EmojiPickerTextareaAdmin
from .models import Message


class MessageForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Message
        fields = ['message', 'test']
        labels = {
            'message': ''
        }
        widgets = {
            'message': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'})
        }
        test = forms.CharField(widget=EmojiPickerTextInputAdmin)
```

Класс модели:

```
class Message(models.Model):
    slug_message = models.SlugField(max_length=150, blank=False, unique=True)
    chat = models.ForeignKey(Chat, on_delete=models.CASCADE, verbose_name='Чат')
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, verbose_name='Автор')
    message = models.TextField(_('Сообщение'))
    date_pub = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.datetime.now())
    is_read = models.BooleanField(default=False, verbose_name='Прочитано')
    is_update = models.BooleanField(default=False, verbose_name='Редактировано')
    date_update = models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank=True)
    test = models.CharField(max_length=2000, blank=True, null=True)
```

Шаблон формы:

```
<form id="message-form" class="panel panel-body" method="post">
                {% load bootstrap3 %}
                {% csrf_token %}
                {{ form }}
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default btn-sm"><span class="ico ico-comment"> 
                </span>Отправить</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте так, кастомное поле должно быть за пределами мета класса:

```
class MessageForm(forms.ModelForm):
    test = forms.CharField(widget=EmojiPickerTextInputAdmin)

    class Meta:
        model = Message
        fields = ['message']
        labels = {
            'message': ''
        }
        widgets = {
            'message': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'})
        }
```

Comment: Да, поле надо было выше поставить и смайл отобразился, но все равно не работает сам смайл, не кликабельный =)